# Types of Components in React (in Total)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component

As I am learning "React" so I have come to know that there are 2 types of components in React:

1. **Class-based**
2. **Functional**

Now, while going through some of the interviews, I came through the following questions:

1. Smart Component
2. Dumb Component
3. Pure Component
4. Impure Component
5. Higher-Order Component

moreover ...

6. Smart vs Dumb Component
7. Pure vs Impure Component
8. Regular vs Pure Component

Now, I am more confused, as I only knew that there are only 2 types of Components. So can someone help me out - What are these other components, or if they are also part of React, `in total what are the different types of Components in React`?

Comment: Practically there are two type of components, the two you named first. The other ones are mainly names for 'type of components based on a design pattern'. A dumb component would (for example) be a component that only receives props and performs no side effects - like a component that renders 'Hello {props.name}'.

Comment: Please add some references to the places, where you have found the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class component is a class with a render method that React will call to get jsx to render and a functional component is a function that React will call passing props to it and the function will return jsx for React to render.

A smart component is a component with logic, if it's a class then maybe the component has local state (`this.state`), if it's a smart functional component then the component may have some hooks (`const [state,setState]=useState(initialState)`).

A dumb component only generates jsx based on passed in props and does not have any logic so a dumb class component only has a render method and a dumb functional component has no hooks.

A pure component only re renders when props passed to it change but when the pure component has hooks it can re render even if props didn't change (like when you use `useSelector` in the component) but technically speaking that component has side effects and isn't pure. A pure class component extends React.PureComponent and a pure functional component does not exist, you can pass a functional component to React.memo but the result of `React.memo(FunctionalComponent)` is not a function. So you can make a new pure component from a functional component using the memo HOC but a pure component is never a function.

Impure component can be a component that has side effects like calling an api method in a class component in the onMount method or an effect in a functional component with useEffect. Also components having any kind of own state (useState or this.state) is not pure.

Higher order component is something like React-Redux connect and React memo. It is a function that receives a component and returns a new component.

Here are some examples (no class components):

```js
//fake api that resolves later
const api = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3]), 2000)
  );

//HOC using props.loading to display loading
const withLoading = (Component) => (props) =>
  props.loading ? 'loading' : <Component {...props} />;
//pure component will only re render when props change
//  also dumb component as it only returns jsx
//  and using HOC React.memo to create List
const List = React.memo(function List({ data }) {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)}</pre>;
});
//this will display loading using the withLoading HOC
const LoadingList = withLoading(List);
//functional impure component (has side effect fetching data and local state)
const App = () => {
  //smart component as App uses state and does more than only return jsx
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({ loading: true });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    api().then((data) =>
      setData({
        loading: false,
        data,
      })
    );
  });
  return <LoadingList {...data} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```